# Difference between * and *&

Tags: c++

When I have defined fnc in a following way:

```
QDialog* get_dialog(Caller* caller);
```

then calling it with my class

```
class Main_Dialog : public Base_Dialog<Ui::Main_Dialog>{};
```

works.

```
//def of Base_Dialog   

template< class Ui_Dialog >
class Base_Dialog : public QDialog, protected Ui_Dialog{};
```

but if I define this fnc as:

```
QDialog* get_dialog(Caller*& caller);   //note ref
```

then code doesn't compile, giving error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Main_Dialog::get_dialog(Main_Dialog* const)'
```

candidate is:

```
template<class Dialog, class Caller> QDialog* Main_Dialog::get_dialog(Caller*&)
```

Isn't that the fnc I'm trying to call? What's wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to pass a reference to a pointer (if that is what you are trying to do)?

Comment: assume you are missing a const in your definition

Comment: @Mat this is related to my previous question when I'm trying to assign new caller to a pointer. I thought maybe by reference it will work. But it won't ;)

Comment: References to pointers make sense if you want to modify the pointer via the reference.

Comment: @SimonRichter that is what I was trying to desperately do.

Comment: @user336635, for the other function to be able to modify the pointer, the function where you are calling it from needs to be able to do it. Most likely the call site is a `const` function, and the pointer object is a member.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to pass in a `const` pointer, but the method requires a non-`const` pointer.

```
QDialog* get_dialog(Caller*& caller);
```

This method requires a reference to a pointer (no `const` anywhere). If you would pass in a non-`const` pointer, it would implicitly be converted to a reference-to-non-`const`-pointer. However, if you are passing in a `const`-pointer, that implicit conversion does not work, so the compiler looks for a function with a signature like:

```
get_dialog(Main_Dialog* const)
```